# convert numbers to word with decimal (java)

Tags: java

I would like to convert the numbers to words, and after a few research, I can convert the numbers to english words successfully. However, this only works for integers. I would like to convert the numbers with decimals to english words, such as:

123.45 -> one hundred twenty three and forty five cents

any solutions?

reference: http://pastebin.com/BNL1tdPW

Comment: Uh well, you have the vast majority of your work done already! This should not be insurmontable, is it?

Comment: what u have done so far, to solve this problem... kindly add it in your question... don't put your assignments here.. it is stackoverflow.com not google....

Comment: @Cross Bone, i am just saying that put your code so that we can help u, on the basis of your question only, we can't help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have all of the basic functionality I will just a pseudo-code suggestion to get the second half:

```
get the cents-only portion as a double. (0.45)
multiply the cents by 100. (45)
use your normal conversion technique to the English words. (Forty Five)
```

**EDIT** (how to get the cents-only portion as a double?):

```
    double money = 123.45;

    int dollars = (int) Math.floor(money);
    double cents = money - dollars;
    int centsAsInt = (int) (100 * cents);

    System.out.println("dollars: " + dollars);
    System.out.println("cents: " + cents);
    System.out.println("centsAsInt: " + centsAsInt);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `BigDecimal`. You can obtain the fractional part as follows:

```
final BigDecimal intPart = new BigDecimal(orig.toBigInteger);
final BigDecimal fracPart = orig.minus(intPart);
final int scale = fractPart.scale();
final String fractPartAsString = fracPart.mult(BigDecimal.TEN.pow(scale));
// treat fractPartAsString
```